# ejabberd detect subscribe request for offline users

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

In ejabberd, I would like to intercept a subscribe request from one user to another, when the other user (to whom the request is being sent) is offline. Is there a specific hook I can use to catch this case? I just want to capture jid of of both )to/from) users and do something with it.

Comment: take  a look at these hooks -roster_in_subscription,roster_get_subscription_lists,roster_out_subscription and resend_subscription_requests_hook.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to use all of them?

Comment: you can use roster_in_subscription hook.

Comment: I did a quick test and looks like both roster_in and roster_out are triggered irrespective of whether the user is online or not. Is that expected behavior? Is there a way to find out at that point, if user is offline or not?

Comment: you can check using session user is online or not .